# Use two fonts in one input box

Tags: javascript, php, html, fonts

I am writing a program in which when a user click on check box , the font of the input (which i am writing) changes. Like firstly if the check box is unchecked the font is 'arial' and when the check box is checked the input font should become 'verdana'.

I am able to do this but the function changes all the previous text written into verdana.

Code Sample:

```
<input type= "checkbox" onchange = "tests();" name="remember" id = "remember"> **(Checkbox)**

function tests(){
        if (remember.checked == 1){
        $(.form-control).css('font-family','verdana');
    }else{
     $('.form-control').css('font-family','arial');
    }

    }
```

i need that whenever i check this , the upcoming data should be in verdana and the previous should remain same in input box.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the font of whole form class `$(.form-control)` do it for specific class of checkbox

**Update:**
add this css

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  font-family:'verdana'
} 
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  font-family:'arial'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code you seem to be using JQuery, so you can do this:

```
$("#remember").change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(".myText").css("font-family", "Verdana");
  } else {
    $(".myText").css("font-family", "Arial");
  }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0js38xab/)